# Where to download file on macs using WebClient?

Tags: c#, macos, webclient

I have an excel file I am downloading using C# and Webclient. The download works but I am wondering if it will also work on a Mac since Macs don't have a C drive.

Here is what I am using:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(file, @"C:\" + guidToken.ToString() + ".xlsx");
```

The file downloads fine on windows, but if someone is using a Mac, will it work and if not, how do I get it to work?

Comment: consider asking the user where you want them to store the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to write my temporary files to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682855/where-to-write-my-temporary-files-to)

Comment: *will it work* - no. *how do I make it work* - is the file intended for the user to use or the program to use?

Answer (score -1):

Use Environmental variables may work.
E.g:

```
string documentpath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```